# Why do I get different output for the programs given below?

Tags: java, multithreading

For this code, numbers are printed from 1-10 for Thread `t1` and after that for thread `t2`.

```
class Synchtest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        synchtest2 a = new synchtest2();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(a);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(a);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class synchtest2 extends Thread {

    public synchronized void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but for the below code they printed as 00 11 22 33 44 55 and so on.

```
class Synchtest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        synchtest2 t = new synchtest2();
        synchtest2 t2 = new synchtest2();
        t.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class synchtest2 extends Thread {

    public synchronized void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, a single synchtest2 instance is used by both threads, as their Runnable, and its `run()` method is synchronized. So the first thread that starts gets the monitor of this unique instance, prints all the numbers, and then releases the monitor, allowing the second thread to run.

In the second example, you have two different instances, and each thread uses its own instance. They thus both acquire their own monitor in parallel (since each object has its own monitor), and happily print their numbers concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are two separate threads, they are running in parallel.

What this means, is that they're basically both printing each number at the same time, which puts them on the same line, instead of inserting a line break between the two.

If you put a slight delay between starting the threads, you would see them posted on different lines.

In your first example, since you are using the same class for both threads, it would finish one before going onto the second. If you wished for a similar result, you would have to wait for the first thread to finish before triggering the second thread.

Answer (score 0):

On the first example you're using the same `Thread` instance twice. They wont run in parallel, because there's only one Thread at a time allowed to get into the instance's `run()` routine.

The second time you create two different instances of `synchtest`, which creates two different threads, which are able to run in parallel.